# Exact word for integrity-less or devoid of any integrity

Tags: single-word-requests

What word can we use to describe someone who has no integrity?

Comment: There are any number of words, depending on both your specific intended context, and exactly what you mean by "integrity". For example, *evil*, *amoral,* and *psychopathic* could all fit, but they're hardly "interchangeable" in all contexts.

Comment: All of those words don't pertain to integrity, but rather to a moral compass or state of mind.

Comment: Phony, fraudster, charlatan, untrustworthy, dishonest, irresponsible, unreliable, deceitful, unscrupulous, perfidious, treacherous, two-faced.

Comment: Even 'integritous' is only accepted as a valid word by a few people, so I'm guessing an inflected antonym isn't available.

Comment: @Kevin: OED **integrity** *Soundness of moral principle; the character of uncorrupted virtue*. Like I said, the question is unanswerable unless/until OP defines exactly which of many possible senses he means by "integrity".

Comment: ...'Double-minded' and 'duplicitous' obviously counter the 'sound' and 'trustworthy' aspects.

Comment: @FumbleFingers my answer intended to address the ambiguity of OP's question, whereas you addressed it with words only in alignment with a moral interpretation of the word "integrity".  Although when the word was created it was meant to reflect purely moral concerns, it has grown to have a much broader definition.  A word like character -- which is used in the definition of disreputable -- was thus more aptly applicable to the ambiguous nature of OP's question.  Ultimately a more specific question would be best.

Comment: A friend suggested 'unscrupulous'. your opinions?

Comment: @Quest: Scruples are very specifically "doubts" in matters of conscience (i.e. - *morality, right/wrong*). An unscrupulous person is normally well aware of his "wrongdoing", but values his own immediate self-interest above morality. An ***amoral*** person (as opposed to *immoral = conscious wrongdoing = unscrupulous*) to me implies he has no *concept* of right and wrong as generally understood. You should edit your question to define exactly what you mean by "lacking integrity". Sometimes having integrity means little more than "being true to one's word", for example.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I was framing a post to address 'How mainstream electronic media has lost it's integrity completely'. Here,I want to know the word which can define this loss of integrity.Electronic media with no integrity at all.

Comment: a pirate, like Blackbeard

Comment: If you're talking about electronic media, it's been Fauxified.

Comment: @Quest: You're simply repeating the word ***integrity***, without saying what you understand (or want) it to mean here. Nation-based broadcast tv, for example, reflects and underpins national integrity. "Stateless" personalised virtual youtube channels don't have or reflect that integrity. Is *that* what you mean? Note that you need to *edit*, rather than comment, if you want the question reopened,

Answer (score 4):

My favorite in these situations:

**unscrupulous**

> having or showing no moral principles; not honest or fair.

Definition from [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=unscrupulous&oq=unscrupulous&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l3&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8)

Answer (score 0):

**Judas**

might work for some.

> Judas Iscariot was, according to the New Testament, one of the twelve
>   original disciples of Jesus Christ, and son of Simon Iscariot. He is
>   known for the kiss and betrayal of Jesus to the Sanhedrin for thirty
>   silver coins.[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judas_Iscariot) His name is often invoked to accuse someone of
>   betrayal. He is sometimes confused with Jude Thaddeus.
>
> Though there are varied accounts of his death, the traditional version
>   sees him as having hanged himself following the betrayal. His place
>   among the Twelve Apostles was later filled by Matthias.
>
> Despite his notorious role in the Gospel narratives, Judas remains a
>   controversial figure in Christian history. Judas' betrayal, for
>   instance, is seen as setting in motion the events that led to Jesus'
>   Crucifixion and Resurrection, which, according to traditional
>   Christian theology, brought salvation to humanity. Gnostic texts –
>   rejected by the mainstream Church as heretical – praise Judas for his
>   role in triggering humanity's salvation, and view Judas as the best of
>   the apostles.[2]
>
> [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Judas_Iscariot)

Answer (score -4):

You might consider **disreputable**

It means someone who doesn't warrant respect based on his or her lack of character -- in this case I think lack of character might be exactly what you are looking for as an antonym for integrity

Comment: This definitely didn't warrant a downvote

Comment: -1 (mine is apparently the *second* downvote) I'm sorry if it looks like I'm only downvoting because you rattled my cage in a comment. But all you've done here is substitute the word ***character*** for ***integrity***. These are both vague terms, so you've effectively raised more questions than you answer here. Define "integrity". Define "character".

Comment: I think you've misinterpreted my response even further.  In no way did I merely "substitute" the word character for integrity.  Disreputable has a highly negative charge, whereas integrity has a neutral charge.  There is a change in charge completely. I don't think I raised any questions at all to be frank.